# GUI Library for making a tool to quickly label images and videos on pixel level

Tags: javascript, python, c++, gui-builder

I want to write a tool to help me generate training data for a machine learning system. The tool would display a picture and ask the user somehow label the pixels of all entities in the scene. The results would look something like the pictures on this page https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/examples/#fine-annotations

I want to write some algorithm that proposes some labels and it would interactively work with the human to refine the pixels. I would also want it to be able to use the current labeling and propose a labeling for the next frame (for video data) so the tool should have at least some rudimentary capability to cycle between a small set of frames and make it appear like an animation.

The user would interact with the tool via mouse clicks or maybe tablet and maybe it would have different buttons to select between different proposal algorithms.

I know C++, python, and a little bit of javascript.

What software should I use to make a tool like this?

Comment: We (disclaimer: I'm one of the developers) have just launched a small open source application: [intellibox](https://gitlab.com/intellisrc/intellibox). Its in java (more specific groovy) though, but easy to modify in case you want to add such algorithm. It uses boxes and images (no video yet), so not sure if you will find it useful (that is why I'm not posting it as an answer). There is a similar tool named [BBox](https://github.com/puzzledqs/BBox-Label-Tool) in which we got inspired. That one is in python.